# What is the convention for sign of rotations in three space?

Tags: linear-algebra

When performing rotations in three space, is a rotation from x to z considered positive or negative? How do you determine whether similar rotations in three space are positive or negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be positive or negative depends on the "direction" of your rotation axis.
The convention is the [right hand rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule).

> If you point your thumb in the "direction" of your rotation axis and
>   you index finger to the direction of the $1^{st}$ vector. If you can
>   point your middle finger to the direction of the $2^{nd}$ vector, then
>   the rotation is considered to be positive. If not, then the rotation
>   is considered to be negative.

In ordinary $\mathbb{R}^3$, the "positive directions" of the 3 axis is setup such
that if you rotate the vector in "positive direction" of $x$-axis with respect to
the "positive direction" of $z$-axis for $90^{\circ}$, you get a vector in the
"positive direction" of $y$-axis.

If you attempt to rotate the vector in "positive direction" of $x$-axis with respect
to the "positive direction" of $y$-axis for $90^{\circ}$, you get a vector in the
"negative direction" of $z$-axis.

So the answer to your original question is "negative" when you measure your rotation with respect to the "positive direction" of $y$-axis.

Sound confusing and hard to remember? Same to me. When in doubt, I always use my right hand to figure out the "sign" of a rotation.